# How do I subtract two columns from the same array and put the value in their own single column array with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subtraction

Lets say i have a single array of 3x4 (3 rows, 4 columns) for example

```
import numpy as np

data = [[0,5,0,1], [0,5,0,1], [0,5,0,1]]

data = np.array(data)

print(data)

[[0 5 0 1]
 [0 5 0 1]
 [0 5 0 1]]
```

and i want to subtract column 4 from column 2 and have the values in their own, named, 3x1 array like this

```
print(subtraction)

[[4]
 [4]
 [4]]
```

how would i go about this in numpy?

Answer (score 4):

```
result = (data[:, 1] - data[:, 3]).reshape((3, 1))
```

Comment: If i do not know how many rows the final array will be, do i put .reshape((-1,1)) instead? Thank you